# how can i change sound amplitude in android?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android, and I need to work with the audio of the android device. I have something like a table of pairs(frequency - amplitude) and I need to set for each frequency the appropriate amplitude, and apply these values to the equalizer of the device, so when a music file is being played, these values will be applied to it.

For example, For frequency 1000 Hz, the amplitude should be 0.5. For frequency 16000 Hz, the amplitude should be 0.8. etc...

I need to apply these values to the android device equalizer so that each frequency in the music file would have its appropriate amplitude.

Thanks in advance :)